# jQuery toggle between two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `bigvideo.js` and want to use a `div` that when clicked pause or play the player.

How can I toggle that on first click it pauses, then if click again played and so on...

```
jQuery('#bigvideo-pause').on('click', function() {
    BV.getPlayer().pause();
    BV.getPlayer().play();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a boolean variable to toggle

```
jQuery('#bigvideo-pause').on('click', function() {
    BV.getPlayer()[this.play ? 'pause' : 'play']();
    this.play = !this.play;
});
```

Comment: I've upvoted, but I'd be tempted to set a property on the node, rather than using a global variable, and rearrange a little: `BV.getPlayer()[this.play ? 'pause' : 'play'](); this.play = !this.play;` (Your approach is far more readable, though).

Comment: Yup , can I add it to my answer